# Import CSV file in MySQL RDBMS

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I need import in db mysql the file excel .xls.

With the google search I realized I need use the **LOAD DATA FILE** syntax and that before you import the excel file in mysql I have to export it in **CSV format** separated by commas.

But I have this problem:

The values of excel file are:

```
N   Val1   Val2    
1   73,4   0,073
```

In the csv file export:

```
N,Val1,Val2         
1,73,4,0,073
```

When I use **LOAD DATA FILE** for import to csv file in db mysql the import on the table is:

```
N   Val1   Val2    
1   73     0
```

In the table the fields Val1 and Val2 are settings as **DECIMAL (10, 2)** values.

I need instead in mysql table:

```
N   Val1   Val2    
1   73,4   0,073
```

I have tried in **LOAD DATA** the replace function, without success:

```
REPLACE(Val1, ',', '.')
```

Anybody know how can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use another separator, like a pipe - "|" - ?